# Random generation with very low chances

Tags: c#, random

I'm trying to get a random bool in C# for a scientific project. The problem is that the chance of the bool being true must be around 10^-12 to 10^-14; the default random function only generates ints and a value between 0 and [u]int.max is far to small.

How can I generate a random boolean value with such a low chance of being true?

Comment: You can get a larger value range if you use `NextBytes`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**EDIT**

## Random.NextDouble() will not give the expected results!

As [Kyle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2779530/kyle) suggests in the comments below, the implementation of `Random.NextDouble()` maps an `int` to the interval [0.0 , 1.0), effectively making my code equivalent to `r.Next( 0, Int32.MaxValue ) == 0`. Adding more zeroes to will not affect the probability of the result being false.

Use one of the other answers, or use this code to generate a ulong (range 0-18446744073709551615) from `System.Random`.

```
var r = new Random();
var bytes = new byte[8];
r.NextBytes(bytes);
ulong result = BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes, 0);
```

---

### Original answer

**Warning: will not work as expected, do not use!** Provided merely for context.

---

Use `Random.NextDouble()` instead: the result is a double between 0.0 and 1.0

```
var r = new Random();
var probablyFalseBool = r.NextDouble() < 0.0000000000001;
```

Vary the number of zeroes if necessary.

Comment: Took this answer because it's the shortest way. You'll be mentioned in the sources section, thanks ;)

Comment: I don't think this will work how you expect.  Based on the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs#bb77e610694e64ca) for System.Random in .NET 4.5, the given code here would result in the same thing as `var probablyFalseBool = r.Next( 0, Int32.MaxValue ) == 0` since `Random.Next` calls the same protected `Sample` method that `Random.NextDouble` calls.

Comment: I agree with @Kyle, the `NextDouble` method has a resolution of `1/Int32.MaxValue` (~1 / 2billion), and therefore is insufficient to use at a resolution you need.

Comment: @Kyle good catch! I edited my answer to steer future users away from using `NextDouble()` for this purpose.

Comment: @Rik Thanks for testing + editing, couldn't check it right now :)

Answer (score 15):

Try combining more than one random selection:

```
if(rnd.Next(0,10000) == 0 && rnd.Next(0,10000) == 0 && rnd.Next(0,10000) == 0){
}
```

Not sure if the C# syntax is correct, but this enter the if block with a probability of  10^-12.

Comment: Beat me by 12 seconds.

Comment: I believe Rik's answer is the easiest and more optimized method.  Combining this solution multiple times is not very pretty, nor very optimized.

Comment: No reason to do this, you can use `NextBytes` to get a larger sample

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, then it became a "bit" complicated to extract values based on a probability in base ten.

Comment: @NathanA BTW, unless OP has some kind of super computer, I doubt he will see any outcome with probability 10^-14.

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin that is very true, but not within scope of the question.  I simply prefer pretty and optimized when possible.

Comment: Optimized in terms of performance? Maybe not. Perhaps the accepted answer will be slower as it uses doubles.

Comment: I do unfortunatly not own a supercomputer, but this project will be on a high-end server for some time (one or more weeks). I did a test script which repeats one billion times:
Empty: 2452 ms
Multi: 22489 ms (20037 ms)
Double: 13865 ms (11413 ms)

The value in brackets is the runtime with the runtime of the empty loop substracted.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `NextBytes` method to get large random numbers.

For example, this will give you the probability of 2.842e-14 that the boolean is `true`:

```
Random r = new Random();
byte[] buffer = new byte[6]; // make an array with 48 bits
r.NextBytes(buffer);
buffer[0] &= 0xf8; // mask out three bits to make it 45
bool occured = buffer.Sum(b => b) == 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

As Nathan suggests, you can use the `Next` method to specify the range of results.

You can then use the `&&` operator to ensure it meets your precision.

```
// 1 in a million
var result = random.Next(0, 1000) == 0 && random.Next(0, 1000) == 0;
```

You can then change them to give you your desired rates.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily control the odds like this:

```
var result = rnd.Next(0,100) == 0;
```

This would make the odds of `result` being true 1 in 100.  You can easily adjust the values to whatever odds you want.

Comment: I don't think that the `Next` method on its own has the appropriate precision.

Comment: This doesn't seem to meet the 1/10,000,000,000,000 odds.

Comment: his requirements specifically state why he can't do this

Comment: @paqogomez The 100 is exclusive, so the value is 0-99, meaning 1 in 100 changes.

Comment: @NathanA What people are saying is that the `Next()` method does not contain the precision necessary - the parameter types are not large enough to hold the value 10,000,000,000,000.

Comment: yup, missed that part. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Go multidimensional! A normal random number is in a single dimension (i.e. along a line). By multiplying two random numbers together you are using two dimensions and so on.

If you take 6 random integers between 1 and 100, then multiply them together the odds of getting the result 1 is 1 in 10^12. Same with four random integers between 1 and 1000, or 3 random integers between 1 and 10000.

If you want something like 30 in 10^12 then use two random numbers between 1 and 1,000,000 and you want one to be 1 and the other 30 or less.

If you want something x (<1,000,000) in 10^12 then use two random numbers between 1 and 1,000,000 and you want one to be 1 and the other x or less.

Answer (score 0):

Generate two ints in a row representing

```
(target_value div int_max, target_value mod int_max)
```

Check the larger for being `0`, the second for being less than `desired_precison * int_max`.

if you have doubt about introducing a bias, randomize the order of the two ints in the pair before testing.

This standalone code illustrates the technique (tested [here](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_csharp_online.php)):

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool   flip, strike;
        int    eps, lo, hi;
        Random rnd;

        eps = Int32.Parse(args[0]); // whatever is appropriate

        rnd = new Random();
        lo = rnd.Next(Int32.MaxValue);
        hi = rnd.Next(Int32.MaxValue);
        flip = (rnd.Next() > 0.5); 
        if (flip) { int swap; swap = lo; lo = hi; hi = swap; }

        strike = (hi == 0) && (lo < eps);

        Console.Write("[hi lo] = ");
        Console.Write(hi);
        Console.WriteLine(lo);
        if (strike) {
            Console.WriteLine("strike");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, but it's performance is bad. Took 38807 ms to execute a billion times, nearly two times as much as the marked approach (19630 ms).

Comment: yes, the calls to the prng should dominate the execution time.

Comment: Nope, must be somewhere else as the 4-times random function is still two times faster. I removed the console outputs and the variable declarations, still not better. The src for the test is [here](http://sebb767.de/img/test.cs).

Comment: in your test code the suggested method fires with probability of about 1 / 2^-(31+31-4) ~ 3.5*10^-18; thus you are about 2 magnitudes below your target threshold!

Comment: Yep, but it's only test code. I'm gonna use this in a big framework with dynamic chance computation, the actual code is `chance = 2.5 * Math.Pow(10, -12) * (((tdx21+tdx12)/2)*(30/3.6)) +              ((2949768/(5.1*(Math.Pow(10, -14))))*(157766400^-1)) * (((tdx21+tdx12)/2)*(30/3.6));` ; unfitting for the benchmark.

Comment: sure, but you tested the code on the premise that it would fire with probability 10^-16, while it was actually < 10^-17. thus the expected runtime should be >10 times that of the competing implementations while it is actually slower by a factor of 2 only. which actually baffles me, because the efficiency of today's fp hardware suggests that riks solution should indeed be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Round.Next` you can use [Round.NextDouble](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextdouble%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Round.NextBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get a much wider range.

With `NextBytes` you can use a buffer of 4-5 bytes to get the range you need. Very roughly, you could do something like this:

```
var buffer=new byte[5];
rnd.NextBytes(buffer);
return buffer.All(b=>b>0);
```

You probably can make this faster by using a [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

With `NextDouble` you would need to check that the result is less than 1/10^12.